# Working with Detached JPA Entities - Transactional Context Issue

Tags: java, jpa, jakarta-ee, ejb, cdi

I am new to developing web services in javaEE (wildfly, ejb, cdi, etc) and I realized that my web service persists back data when changes happen to its jpa entities. However I want the entities to be only detached. How do I pull data and only work in detached mode for all queries that may happen in my web service?

The db select queries all happen in a ejb because I think the container managed transactional context provides me with timeout callback which I might lose in a cdi bean. How do I keep the timeout mechanism but work with detached entities which may be manipulated without persisting changes back?

Thanks in advance guys

Comment: You can detach any particular entity by calling EntityManager.detach(entity). You can detach all entities that are currently associated with an EntityManager by calling EntityManager.clear().

Comment: Do I lose container managed timeout when using Not_Supported Transation Context?

Comment: I don't know. If I did, I would have given you an answer rather than a comment. Good luck!

Comment: What do you mean with "Do I lose container managed timeout"??? NOT_SUPPORTED_TRANSACTION means (assuming that you're talking about EJBs) that your EJB does not join to the current transaction if there is one (in this case, the timeout is still going) or does not open a new Transaction if there is no Tx (in this case, there no timeout because there is no Tx)....

Comment: By the way, why do you need a transaction if you are not modifing/persisting anything??

Comment: @CarlitosWay for the timeout support? instead of waiting in case no internet connection the timeout will break through in 5 seconds or 10
am i right?